# Listen Remote Computer Port

Tags: c#, port, listen

I want to have a console application (C#) which listens a socket port on a remote computer. I want to run that application on my computer and want it to listen a port on a remote computer, i have IP, Port, User, Password information of that remote computer. Can i do that ?

I know how to listen a port on the local computer, i have a console application (acts as server) that keeps listening my computer's port (like port 8001) and whenever there is a request, it detects it, fulfill the requirement and send response to the client. I want the same thing but want to put the listener on some other computer.

Please tell me is it possible to listen remote computer's port, if yes please provide a direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i do that ?

No, you will have to install and run the application on the remote computer. Since you already have administrative privileges on that computer that wouldn't be too much of a problem for you.